# I want to catch InputMismatchException but it shows compile time error

Tags: java, exception, compilation, inputmismatchexception

I get the following error while compiling:

```
filimon.java:12: error: cannot find symbol
                }catch(InputMismatchException ime){
                       ^
  symbol:   class InputMismatchException
  location: class filimon
1 error
```

My source code is:

```
class filimon{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
        try{
            System.out.println("enter 2 integer values");
            int a=s.nextInt();
            int b=s.nextInt();
            System.out.println("value of a: "+a);
            System.out.println("value of b: "+b);
        }catch(InputMismatchException ime){
            System.err.println("please enter only number value");
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.err.println(e);
        }
    }//main
}//filimon
```

What is the problem? Please help me.

Comment: What are your imports?

Comment: Undoubtedly you have not identified to the compiler what package holds the `InputMismatchException` type. Also, you don't handle the exception, and `catch(Exception e)` is an antipattern. Please follow the naming conventions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add import java.util.InputMismatchException;

Answer (score 0):

Java can't find `InputMismatchException` because it isn't imported.

[`InputMismatchException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/InputMismatchException.html) is located in `java.util`.

At the top of your file, write

```
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
```

to import just the exception, or

```
import java.util.*;
```

to import everything in `java.util`.

As a sidenote, the

```
catch(Exception e)
```

is not a good idea. It is better to list each exception that you would like to catch, either in its own catch block, or like this:

```
catch(InputMismatchException|NoSuchElementException e){
```